# Patent Sponsorship

Tags: patent-services, sponsor, cost

I have an idea/product that I want to patent, but I live outside the US and I don't have the money for all the huge expense that is to patent something.

Are there investors that are interested in sponsoring a patent? By sponsor I mean, they will pay for all the patent procedures and costs and later they will have a percentage of the profits on the patent/product sale.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. We are set up to answer questions about how the U.S. patent system works and for requests to help find prior for pending or issued U.S. patents Question about finding investors are outside of our on-topic areas.

Comment: Oh that's disappointing :/ most people I talk the only problem they see is getting the money for the patent....

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that you will find an investor who would pay for the patent -- typically investors are investing in a company and team to build a product and business.

With a provisional patent you are able to file for very little money which you have 12 month to build a successful product.

Patents are too easy to write (relatively speaking) for the majority to be worth anything without a product and business to prove their value.

Comment: I am afraid of make a provisional patent by myself and then some company will read it and find a "hole" and file a patent, making my own patent useless in the future...I am not a specialist, what do you think about this scenario?

Comment: Provisional patents are not published, at least not within the first 12 months (not sure if ever published) -- make sure you idea is fully and detailed described in a provisional patent and you should be fine.   The bigger risk is if you don't file, as different person would be able to file for the same idea and you would have nothing to show you were first if you didn't have a provisional patent filed.

Comment: Do I have to submit drawings in the provisional as well? Are there any good links on tips and tricks on provisional patents?

Comment: Write as complete description as possible -- there is no particular format for a provisional patent -- it is just a detailed technical description without any claims -- the better you describe it the better you stand a when it comes to getting the final patent written.

Comment: Do you think it's better to ask for a patent lawyer to make one for me? I believe it will be A LOT cheaper than a patent filling, right?

Comment: Patent lawyers will charge you about the same for filing a provisional and a non-provisional patents as they work to either is almost the same for them -- provisional patents are mostly suitable for do-it-yourself, and a patent lawyer will most likely advice  filing a non-provisional.

Comment: I am not american, and I am not in the USA, will I be able to file it myself anyways?

Comment: Depends on what country you are from -- some countries have laws against filing inventions with foreign governments.  You will need somebody with understanding of your local laws to answer that, but otherwise you can file it yourself.

Comment: I live in Brazil, I don't think there is such a law in here...I am more worried about how to file it in the USA and paying for it...but I guess it must be 100% online...

Comment: You can do it online, or you can do it by registered post -- payment has to be in US dollars -- have sent a check with the posting when I have done it. http://www.uspto.gov/patents/resources/types/provapp.jsp.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! Do you have any link on provisional patents examples? This way I can see the way they are generally written (technology products are preferred is possible since it's more relevant to my case)